# Netbeans keep acting strange. Can I get it fixed or install a better IDE with recommended plugins?

Tags: installation, gedit, netbeans

But the problem is, today is my third day using ubuntu, and I find it is amazing.
Except I just can't setting a good IDE.

Netbeans is my IDE on Win8 and maybe my favoriate IDE  on ubuntu.
Here is the thing:

> 1 First I install netbeans using apt-get and installed with a netbeans versioned 7.0.1.
>
> 2 But it can't create a project or running one with existing codes and keep saying :
>   loading Projects ( I thought it was someting wrong with netbeans but turns out to be the wrong version of my java jdk).
>
> 3 So I install ,or update, can't figure out what that line of code means yet, 
>   **java jdk**.
>   And now netbeans is working ok except sometime can't fold my codes or stuck ASAP I use code **autocomplete**.

#### or

If I can't fix my netbeans, I hope someone can recommend me a new editor with plugins.

A nice editor like gedit works pretty well except it could be a little uncomfotable when I am working with more than 20 methods in a class... LOL
So, If there r some available plugins like:

> 1 code folding plugins
>
> 2 autocomplete plubgins

I will be trully thanksful.

### Summary :

> 1 how to fix netbean
>
> 2 or how can I get good editor with plugins

Answer (score 0):

1 Download Netbeans from [their website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and follow their installation instructions

2 Have a look at [Geany](http://www.geany.org/), IMO the best editor around (and it has plugins...)

Comment: my netbeans 7.3.1 is downloaded from their website, but maybe something wrong or I mess up with something...Just don't understand. I have downloaded geany,but feel unfamiliar with its GUI and hot keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org). It has way more extensions than NetBeans, it is more powerful altogether, and works far better on Linux.

Comment: I used to use Eclipse on windows, it is great, but I fell netbeans is more friendly,well, at least on windows. >1 Does Eclipse have color Theme preference?